# Transferir archivos de PC de escritorio a notebook usando FileZilla Client y FileZilla Server

Tags: filezilla

Pues mi duda es esa. Hay muchos tutoriales en Internet donde explican cómo hacerlo, pero todos lo explican usando la misma PC, y yo quiero hacerlo teniendo el server en la notebook y el client en la PC de escritorio.

En el server ya creé un usuario (en mi caso lo llame root) al que no le asigné contraseña.
Ya elegí la carpeta que voy a compartir en Shared folders (en mi caso se llama MiFTP).
En options, en la parte de Passive mode settings, seleccioné "Use the following IP:" y escribí mi dirección IPv4.

Después, en la PC de escritorio, en el FileZilla clent, cuando pongo mi IP en el campo servidor, el usuario, la contraseña, y el puerto en valor 21, no conecta. En resumen, no hace nada.

**Editado**

Luego intenté abriendo el puerto 21. Fui a Panel de Control -> Sistema y Seguridad -> Firewall de Windows Defender -> Configuración avanzada -> Reglas de Entrada (aclaro que tengo Windows 10)

En las opciones de la derecha elegí Nueva Regla.
En la ventana, en Tipo de regla, seleccioné Puerto.
En Protocolo y puertos, seleccioné TCP y escribí 21 en el campo Puertos locales específicos.
En Acción, seleccioné Permitir la conexión.
En Perfil, dejé todas las opciones marcadas (estaba así por defecto).
Y por último, en Nombre, le puse un nombre cualquiera (en mi caso escribí TCP 21).

Clic en Finalizar y reinicié la notebook. Abrí el server de nuevo, puse los valores en el client que tengo en la PC. Nada, sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: abriste el puerto 21 en el firewall de tu maquina que sirve como servidor?

Comment: No, y tampoco sé como hacerlo.

Comment: https://wiki.mcneel.com/es/zoo/window7firewall este tutorial podría ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Avisa si logras solucionar el problema, y publica la respuesta a tu pregunta para que se pueda cerrar el hilo.

Comment: Entendido. Gracias.

Comment: Abrí el puerto y sigue sin funcionar. Ahí edité el post.

Comment: Está la notebook conectada por cable o wifi?  Puede ping la notebook del escritorio?  Puede telnet a puerto 21 del escritorio a la notebook?

Comment: La notebook está conectada por WiFi al router. La PC está conectado por cable a ese mismo router.